# Does Select2 support conditional/function option values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Maybe my Google-Fu is off today but I just can't for the life of me figure out whether or not Select2 4.0.2 supports functions as the values for options. Looking like a "no" from my fumbling around but worth a try, right?

Here's what I have which does not work:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    minimumResultsForSearch: function() {
      return $(this).hasClass('taggable') ? 0 : 8;
    },
    tags: function() {
      $(this).hasClass('taggable');
    },
    width: "100px"
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
<select class="taggable">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

Does Select2 support functions as the value of options? If so, what stupidly simple thing am I doing wrong?

I have seen similar questions asking how to change the options on-the-fly which isn't *exactly* what I'm looking for - I just don't want to repeat myself if I can help it - so fingers crossed this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Why the instant downvote? Can I improve the question or is this information readily available and I need more coffee?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. I can only assume someone missed the hidden snippet, so I set it to expand for you

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind moving forward.